# How can I write multiple DataFrames to a MySQL database?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have data in several DataFrames that I would like to write to different tables in MySQL. I want it so that they all succeed or none of them.

I've been using the `to_sql()` method with `create_engine()` from sqlalchemy sequentially but if say the 1st succeeds and the 2nd one fails, I can't roll back the 1st.

Comment: After your code ran, write another part which checks if all tables exist, if one of them don't, remove the tables. There's no such thing as "rollback" when writing data with python to a database.

Comment: There is if you use SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the context_manager functionality in SQLAlchemy to achieve this functionality. Take a look at [the documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html), as well as [this post](https://capelastegui.wordpress.com/2018/05/21/commit-and-rollback-with-pandas-dataframe-to_sql/).

Comment: I dont know why this got downvoted, it's a solid answer. Thank you.

Comment: "Link only" -answers are usually frowned upon. Even though links are great, the answer itself should be an answer instead of just a sign post to the answer. Link rot is also a real thing. Some may even flag such as "not an answer": https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer